# Does swift contain something like threads?

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift, coming from C styled syntax languages (C#, java..). I've been given a past exam paper asking questions about Swift. I've came across one question;

> A developer is building an iOS application that needs to obtain data over a network
>   connection. She is aware that it may take some time to process, but does not want the
>   application user interface to become unresponsive whilst the task executes. Outline the
>   steps she could take to achieve this, referring to the features available in the language
>   she might use.

The first thing that comes to mind is to use threads, and run this process on a separate thread, but from my understanding, threads do not exist in Swift. What's the best answer to this question?

Comment: Yes. You want to google `Dispatch Queues in Swift`

Comment: Keep in mind that Swift's `URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url)` is already set up to run asynchronously and call its completion afterwards; you don't need to create the request's thread yourself.

Comment: Technically, Swift does not contain threads. The OS provides threading. The OS SDK provides an API at various levels to use queues and threads. There just happens to be a Swift binding to this API.

Comment: Thread exist in Swift. Check for threads in swift iOS

Comment: Swift does have [thread](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/thread) but they are not commonly used in high-level code. The prevailing pattern is to use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/DISPATCH) for such task as network request.

Comment: Apple's [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse *language* features with *system* features.

iOS certainly has ways to let you network asynchronously, and in particular to do [a time-consuming download in the background](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessionconfiguration/1407496-background). Indeed, by default *all* networking is asynchronous on a background thread; networking on the main thread would be a bug in your program. [The question you quoted was probably intended to elicit your knowledge of those features, of which it appears you have none.]

But all of that has nothing to do with what *language* you use to program iOS.